# TSQL: comma combination, transaction?

Tags: t-sql, transactions

Given the following:

```
select * from a; 
select * from b;
```

Are these two statements run in an implicit transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default transaction mode in SQL Server is [autocommit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213069(SQL.80).aspx), unless you specify otherwise.  This means that every statement is run in its own transaction; if one fails, all of the preceding statements still succeed.

You can change this with either a `BEGIN TRAN` statement (explicit transaction) or `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON` (turns on implicit transactions).  Note that if you enable implicit transactions, only the `BEGIN` is implicit - you still need to explicitly `COMMIT`.

It's also generally considered bad practice to use implicit transactions; it tends to lead to buggier scripts due to transactional boundaries not being clearly visible.